# select specific item from typeahead list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap. I've got the following code. When you click on an item from a typeaheadlist, a popover will open. But what I want to do is, when you click on a specific item, only then the popover should open.

```
$('#nr1').typeahead({
    source: source,
    updater: function(item) {
        $('#nr1').popover({
            placement: 'bottom',
            content: function(e) {
                return $('.addnr').html();
            }
        }).popover('show');
        return item;
    }
})
```

I tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
$('#nr1').typeahead({
    source: source,
    updater: function(item) {
        $('li').val('').on('click', function(item){
            $('#nr1').popover({
                placement: 'bottom',
                content: function(e) {
                    return $('.addnr').html();
                }
            }).popover('show');
        });
        return item;
    }
})
```

As you can see the li has a data-value=''.

Comment: what is the JSON? And HTML..? .addnr is ...?

Comment: I'm not using JSON. .addnr is a div that i want to put in the popover

Comment: So, what is the `data-value` then? and HTML-skeleton?

Comment: typeahead creates a list from the arrays in the variable "source". I see in "inspect element" that it's creates <ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu"><li data-value= "example" class="active">

Comment: Nevermind I already figured it out.